# Hide UIPageControl of UIPageControlViewController on certain page index

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to hide the page control indicator on a certain VC and instead show a button with the text 'Get started'. The user has however still be able to navigate back into the page control.

I've tried this:

```
self.pageController = [UIPageControl appearance];
self.pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

if(self.pageIndex == 1){
    self.pageController.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"hide you!");
}
```

However, this doesn't work. setting `self.pageController.hidden = YES` without the if statement works, and the nslog is triggered as well. It seems that somehow this can only be set once.

I also don't know how smooth this will be. I obviously don't want it to change when the user is fully arrived on the page itself, but in the transition toward it.

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 5):

I made it with swift, maybe it will help -

```
func setPageControlHidden (hidden: Bool)
{
    for subView in self.view.subviews
    {
        if subView is UIScrollView
        {
            subView.frame = self.view.bounds
        }
        else if subView is UIPageControl
        {
            subView.hidden = hidden
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me it was `parent.view` instead of `self` cause I'm  calling it inside a specific page to hide the controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may set the hidesForSinglePage to YES, this will reset the hidden property when the numberOfPages is greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the space where UIPageControl was located, you can change view's frame so page control is out of screen:

```
func togglePageControl(visible: Bool) {
    if let pageVC = parent as? UIPageViewController {
        // find UIPageControl
        for case let control in pageVC.view.subviews where control is UIPageControl {
            let height = control.frame.height
            if visible {
                pageVC.view.frame.size.height -= height
            } else {
                pageVC.view.frame.size.height += height
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in UIViewController you want with hidden page control (check for visibility is because viewWillAppear is called even when user starts swiping to other screen and then interrupts this action):

```
var isPageControlVisible = true

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if isPageControlVisible {
        togglePageControl(visible: false)
        isPageControlVisible = false
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    togglePageControl(visible: true)
    isPageControlVisible = true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for subView in self.view.subviews where subView is UIPageControl {
            subView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```